# Предложение помечать вопросы статусом [Решено]

Tags: обсуждение, предложение

Часто наталкиваясь на вопросы без выбранного ответа, а порой и вообще без ответов, где просто кто-то помог автору в комментариях, в голову пришла мысль помечать такие вопросы дополнением к заголовку: [Решено]. Таким образом, большинство пользователей не будут тратить свое время, видя, что на вопрос нет ответов или не выбран правильный ответ.

Comment: а как ты узнаешь, что вопрос действительно _решен_?

Comment: 1. Автором была допущена банальная ошибка в подключении к БД, скажем. 2. Автор сказал "спасибо, все работает" своим последним сообщением.

Comment: _1. Автором была допущена банальная ошибка в подключении к БД, скажем._ - в этом случае подобный вопрос наверняка уже был задан, и следует закрывать как дубликат, либо если была допущена опечатка, то закрывать как содержащий опечатку.

Comment: Но в предложенном Вами обсуждении решения так и не было найдено, и будет ли оно вообще найдено?

Comment: В любом случае, для приведенного примера решение простое: голосование за закрытие либо написание своего ответа. _Таким образом, большинство пользователей не будут тратить свое время, видя, что на вопрос нет ответов или не выбран правильный ответ._ - с точки зрения каких пользователей рассматривается трата времени?

Comment: С точки зрения тех, кто пришел на сервис с целью помочь или просто наработать себе карму, отвечая на вопросы.

Comment: Некоторые уже так делают https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=title%3Aрешено+is%3Aquestion

Comment: @VadimTagil, я просто хотел, чтобы это было какой-то общепринятой практикой, но раз кто-то ставит такие статусы самостоятельно, значит кому-то так удобно, спасибо.

Comment: @VadimTagil там 6 вопросов за последний год.  Это новички,  которые не смогли найти зеленую галку для отметки ответа.

Comment: Я рекомендовал бы не делать правки [подобные этой](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/201734). Ваша тема не нашла поддержки в сообществе, поэтому при большом числе отклонённых правок вам автоматчески будет закрыт доступ к инструментам модерирования.

Comment: Хорошо, прислушаюсь к мнению большинства

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Если кто-то просто помог автору в комментариях, то это совершенно не означает, что вопросу не нужен ответ!

Любой участник может собрать комментарии вместе, добавить воды от себя, найти ссылок или, наоборот, пересказать своими словами информацию на которую ссылаются, написать пример кода если нужно - и сделать все это аккуратным ответом, получив заслуженные плюсы за старание.

С другой стороны, если ошибка была настолько глупая, что ответа из комментариев собрать не получится при всем желании - вопрос надо закрывать как опечатку *("Вопрос вызван проблемой, которая больше не воспроизводится, или опечаткой")*.

То же самое можно сделать с брошенными вопросами от пропавших авторов, но только если у них низкий рейтинг и малое число просмотров. И надо сначала убедиться, что автор **действительно** пропал, а то были случаи... Лучше сначала написать комментарий про "галочку", а начинать предпринимать какие-то действия только если такой комментарий провисел уже хотя бы неделю.

Если же у ответа хороший рейтинг - система считает, что на вопрос ответ уже дан, поэтому особых действий не требуется. Кажется, такие вопросы в списке неотвеченных не показываются.

Еще есть вариант - создание нового вопроса с самоответом по мотивам старого, с последующим закрытием старого как дубликата нового и просьбой модератору перенести ответы. Но это совсем уж запасной вариант, для случаев когда, к примеру, ответ значительно лучше вопроса.

Comment: Почему сразу воды-то добавить? Многие знакомые мне участники, наоборот, цемента добавляют.

Answer (score 4):

Надпись `[Решено]` и наличие принятого ответа - совершенно разные по заметности, поэтому, даже если предположить, что какая-то пометка имеет смысл (что само по себе весьма спорно), то явно не такая. Уровень заметности должен быть примерно одинаковым, либо принятый ответ должен быть заметнее.

Что касается ответов в комментариях, их надо просто брать и переделывать в ответы.

И по-поводу вопросов без ответов - я при поиске решения в них тоже заглядываю, т. к. сам код в вопросе может натолкнуть на какую-то мысль.