# Убирать ли из заголовка отметки типа [решено], [всё ещё актуально] и т.п.?

Tags: предложение, вопросы, заголовок

В [комментарии](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5993/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%8B-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%A0%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BE#comment22947_5993) к соседнему вопросу выяснилось, что существует хоть и небольшое по масштабам общего объёма, но всё же состоящее из [нескольких десятков](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=title%3A%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BE%20is%3Aquestion) кол-во вопросов с пометкой `[решено]` в заголовке. Также возможны и другие пометки от автора вопроса, говорящие о некотором "статусе" вопроса, например, `[всё ещё актуально]`.

Считаю, что подобные отметки надо с вопросов незамедлительно выпиливать, т.к. заголовок должен отражать суть вопроса, а не его состояние или что-то ещё.

Comment: Поддерживаю. Только не забывайте,  что при правее старых вопросов нужно исправлять все проблемы в вопросе, а не просто править заголовок

Comment: @PashaPash все видимые и очевидные для редактора. Всё-таки никто не идеален и редакторы тоже не могут знать всех нюансов и правил.

Comment: К пометкам относится дублирование меток в заголовке вопроса?

Comment: @Visman об этом [отдельная статья](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3480/176217) есть

Answer (score 8):

Выпиливать однозначно.

Такое обычно по моим наблюдениям проставляет сам топикстартер, который привык к такому "форумному" стилю. На форумах это удобно, позволяет зрительно фильтровать темы.

Но у нас надо пользоваться галкой.

Принятый ответ подсвечивается в списке вопросов -- и это намного лучше капса в заголовке.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А при [расширенном поиске](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/searching) -- использовать `hasaccepted:no`.

Поэтому и нужно приучать других к галкам (давать в комментариях совет топикстартеру принять ответ) и выпиливать неправильное использование.

Не вижу смысла поощрять неправильные сценарии использования.

Answer (score 0):

Идейно я согласен с ответом @AK, но есть нюанс. Мне кажется не стоит ворошить сайт в поисках подобных вопросов. Случайно попался (Дух поднял, либо сам по ссылкам забрёл) - возьми и поправь, а делать массовую вычистку из всякого старья я смысла не вижу.

Comment: А Вы собираетесь в модераторы?

Comment: @alexolut, конечно.

Comment: Тогда массовую вычистку лучше бы поддержать!